# Changing Dropdown attribute to text in magento 1.9 without changing data

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, dropdown-attribute, convert, text-field

***In Magento 1.9, I am going to convert my drop-down attributes to text field without changing my current data***

***Below is the image of current attribute set***

[image: My current attribute to convert]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of update statements that should change the data-type from int to varchar (should be the case for all non-numeric text fields), changes input-type from select to text, and migrates all of the existing data into the correct tables. You should be able to run these in either order, then just re-index and you're done!

Update attribute settings:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute
SET 
    backend_type = 'varchar',
    frontend_input = 'text'
WHERE attribute_id = [add the attribute id];
```

Insert values from the old table into the new table:

```
insert into catalog_product_entity_varchar
(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
(
    select 
        cpei.entity_type_id, 
        cpei.attribute_id, 
        cpei.store_id, 
        cpei.entity_id, 
        eaov.value
    from eav_attribute_option eao
    join eav_attribute_option_value eaov
    on eao.option_id = eaov.option_id
    join catalog_product_entity_int cpei
    on eao.option_id = cpei.value
    where cpei.attribute_id = [one or more attribute_ids of your choosing]
)
```

**hope its work for you**